# In angular-ui-bootstrap's typeahead, how can I use a custom popup template AND custom item template?

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

Using https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ typeaheads

It doesn't look like I'm able to add a custom popup template AND a custom item template.

I've tried changing this in my custom popup:

```
<div uib-typeahead-match index="$index" match="match" query="query" typeahead-template-url="app/components/localIntentsPicker/typeahead-item.html"></div>
```

I can remove this div and just add my own changes in-line, but then I lose keyboard control over typeahead selection.

I've also tried adding the following to my main typeahead input.

```
typeahead-template-url="app/components/localIntentsPicker/typeahead-li.html
```

Neither seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was doing a few things wrong.

Item template code needs to be wrapped in `<a>` to maintain keyboard selection.

Most importantly, wrapping template-url in extra quotes fixed the issue:

```
<div uib-typeahead-match index="$index" match="match" query="query" template-url="'app/components/localIntentsPicker/typeahead-item.html'"></div>
```